# Source refactoring using shell

Tags: bash, shell, sed, find, refactoring

I have a requirement similar to refactoring option in eclipse but to be done from command line.
Refactoring here means to rename a particular entity be it a file or a directory to some other name and also update its references everywhere in the source code.

Basically, I need to modify the parent folder names to something else and in each and every file, search for that folder name and replace it with new folder name.
Eg: my current package is app_demo , i want to change it to app_demo_new . Also wherever , the app_demo is imported in the source code throughout, i have to replace it with app_demo_new
eg:

```
import com.site.app_demo.*
```

should be replaced by

```
import com.site.app_demo_new_.*
```

I tried:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/oldname/newname/g' {} +
```

This gives an error:

```
find: missing argument to -exec
```

Any suggestions how to achieve this level of deep refactoring to all files, folder and content of files?

Comment: Saying `similar to refactoring option in eclipse` means absolutely nothing to many of us since we have no idea what `eclipse` is so if that statement is intended to convey some information not expressly stated in the rest of your question then please edit your question to clarify. Also, there are no `folders` in UNIX terminology, you probably mean `directories` unless `folder` has some meaning in `eclipse` that's different from what it means in Windows. Also, post some sample input and expected output as we can't tell from a script that does not work what you really wanted it to do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the `+` in the end of command means. I usually add `\;` at the end of commands, like

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/oldname/newname/g' {} \;
```